# Variable caption on checkboxes using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the following code that creates checkboxes based on the values from a recordset, which can be A, B,C or D.
I want the checkboxes caption to show what those letters mean. For example, A= Excelent, B= Very Good, C= Good, D= Bad.
I have those values in a sheet and do a vlookup to get the corresponding name, so the code is currently doing the desired, but is there a way to not have these values in a sheet, perhaps in a variable or in a hidden sheet?

```
If Not rst.EOF And Not rst.BOF Then
    i = 0
    Do
        With MultiPage1.Pages(2).Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
            .Top = yPos
            .Left = 7
            .Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rst![Perspect], ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b26:c30"), 2, False)
            .Width = 450
            .Height = 24
            .WordWrap = True
            .Value = False
            yPos = yPos + 17
            .Tag = rst![Perspect]
            i = i + 1
            rst.MoveNext
        End With
    Loop Until rst.EOF
    rst.Close
End If
```

Comment: *"I have those values in a sheet … is there a way to … in a hidden sheet?"* What's wrong with just hiding the sheet?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ if I hide the sheet, the vlookup function would not work. Or at least it does not work for me

Comment: Is it possible to get those values in recordset? Perhaps you could craft a CASE expression in your SQL that uses the values from the sheet so the values are present in the rst.

Comment: Try `Application.VLookup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to put it in your recordset. If you don't have that option, then I think this is the cleanest way:

Replace the `.Caption = ...` with

```
 .Caption = GradeCaption(rst![Perspect])
```

And then create your function:

```
Function GradeCaption(Grade As String) As String
    Select Case Grade
        Case "A"
            GradeCaption = "Excellent"
        Case "B"
            GradeCaption = "Very Good"
        Case "C"
            GradeCaption = "Good"
        Case "D"
            GradeCaption = "Bad"
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could help

```
Function getVal(strLetter As String)

Dim a() As Variant

Dim b() As Variant

a = Array("Gold", "Silver", "Bronze")
b = Array("A", "B", "C")

Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Index( _
                a, 1, _
                Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strLetter, b, 0))
End Function
```

Calling like so

`getVal("B")` gives silver, `getVal("C")` gives bronze etc

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities to reach your goal: a sheet, a hidden sheet, arrays, a dictionary ... attached a possibility with select case:

```
Sub Call_GetDescr()
    MsgBox "A: " & getDescription("A")
    MsgBox "B: " & getDescription("B")
    MsgBox "C: " & getDescription("C")
    MsgBox "D: " & getDescription("D")
    MsgBox "X: " & getDescription("X")
End Sub

Function getDescription(inputStr As String) As String
Dim result As String
    Select Case inputStr
        Case "A"
            result = "very good"
        Case "B"
            result = "good"
        Case "C"
            result = "sufficient"
        Case "D"
            result = "bad"
        Case Else
            result = "not defined"
    End Select
    getDescription = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Always been a fan of dictionaries for these types of problems. 
May I suggest.

```
Sub GradeDictionary()
Dim dict As Object, key, val
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

key = "A": val = "Excellent"
dict.Add key, val

key = "B": val = "Very Good"
dict.Add key, val

key = "C": val = "Good"
dict.Add key, val

key = "D": val = "Bad"
dict.Add key, val

For Each k In dict.Keys
    ' Print key and value
    Debug.Print k, dict(k)
Next

End Sub
```